# Checking for even-odd levels of a min-max heap java

Tags: java, heap, max, min, depth

So this is a method I wrote to determine if a given index of an array represents a max level or a min level of a heap, where min level has even depth (including 0), max level has odd depth. It works fine, but its run time is (I think) O(log N). Is there a more efficient way of doing this like a simple math calculation that has a constant run time? Note that this method assumes the data starts at index 1 of the array, not index 0.

```
    private boolean isMaxLevel(int i)
    {
    int border = 1;
    int prev = 1;
    int count = 1;
    boolean isMax = false;
    // alternates boolean between true and false as each level is checked.
    while (true)
        {
        if (i >= prev && i <= border)
            return isMax;
        isMax = !isMax;
        prev = border + 1;
        count *= 2;
        border += count;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Its not clear to me what your requirement is but this might help you.

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= 256; i *= 2) {
        System.out.println((i - 1) + ": " + isOddHighestBit(i - 1));
        System.out.println(i + ": " + isOddHighestBit(i));
    }
}

public static boolean isOddHighestBit(int i) {
    return (Double.doubleToRawLongBits(i) >> 52) % 2 == 0;
}
```

prints

```
0: true
1: false
1: false
2: true
3: true
4: false
7: false
8: true
15: true
16: false
31: false
32: true
63: true
64: false
127: false
128: true
255: true
256: false
```

Comment: Your function given the input (i+1) will work :) Nicely done with the bit shifting, I can't believe I didn't think of that given the log being base 2 and all haha. isMaxLevel would just become: `return (Double.doubleToRawLongBits(i+1) >> 52) % 2 == 1;` nice and quick :) My only question is why exactly 52 bits shited? How does that always give the highest bit? Does it have to do with it being a double and not a long?

Comment: The lowest 52 bits of a double is the mantissa, the next 11 is the exponent (log2(i) which is what we want) I am assuming the sign is 0 (positive)

Comment: `Math.log` is relatively expensive.  Using doubleToRawLongBits took 3 ns on machine on average, Using logs took 54 ns on average.

Comment: I'm aware that log is slow, I said in my post I didn't know if it was even as fast as his `O(log n)` loop. Thanks for explaining the 52nd bit thing! That's a handy thing to know :)

Comment: Depending on how often you this 54 ns is not slow. ;)

Comment: That bit shifting solution works really well, however i modified your solution to be % == 1 instead of == 0, as paul has in his post, so I didnt have to change my solution of my min max heap :)   We actually just got started talking about binary and hex stuff in my data structures class, and we haven't really covered bit shifting yet but the prof showed us a quick example of it. Really cool to actually see it applied like this. However the log solution was good too, got me thinking more about how to solve equations to base algorithms on. Thanks for the replies!

Comment: Using `% n == 0` or `%n != 0` is a better solution in some cases as `-1 % 2 == -1` not `1`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this in any faster, it's probably implementation dependent, but:

```
private boolean isMaxLevel(int i){
    if(((int)Math.log(i+1)/Math.log(2)))%2 == 1)
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

Returns the correct value. Think of it mathematically. You want to find out for which n the following is true about i. If n is odd you have a max level, if n is even you have a min level.

`2ⁿ-1 <= i < 2ⁿ⁺ⁱ-1`

Solving this for n we get:

```
2ⁿ-1 <= i < 2ⁿ⁺ⁱ-1
2ⁿ <= i+1 < 2ⁿ⁺ⁱ
n <= log₂(i+1) < n+1
n = floor(log₂(i+1))
```

Then we can just test if n is odd (n%2 == 1)

Comment: I really don't imagine that would be any faster...`Math.log` is considerably slower than bit shifting.  So is modulo, which can be replaced by bit shifting for powers of 2.

Answer (score 0):

we have to detect the min level and max level ranges

1   => pow(2,0)                -->min level

2-3 => pow(2,1) to pow(2,2)-1  -->max level

4-7 => pow(2,2) to pow(2,3)-1  -->min level

8-15 => pow(2,3) to pow(2,4)-1  -->max level

c implementation

```
#include<math.h>
#define bool int
#define true 1
#define false 0
int isMinLevel(int i,int n)//i is on min level or not
{
  int h=2;
  if(i==1)
    return true;
  while(true)
    {
      if(i>=pow(2,h)&&i<=pow(2,h+1)-1)
    return true;
      else if(i>n||i<pow(2,h))
    return false;
      h+=2;
    }
}
```