# Understand how min-max heap looks like after after delete-min and delete-max

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, minmax-heap

I have a specific question about min-max heap related problem in Java.

If you have inputs in this order:

```
71, 8, 41, 100, 60
```

Would the tree look like the following?

```
                   8
           100           41
       70       60
```

What about after `deleteMin` and `deleteMax`?

I am trying to understand what would happen if the max node is somehow smaller than some of the min nodes... If you can help me by explaining it with a tree that would be great :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6796196/checking-for-even-odd-levels-of-a-min-max-heap-java 
I think this one will be helpful

Comment: I still don't quite understand what the tree should look like after the operations though...

Answer (score -2):

The process of creating the min heap of this inputs is this:

```
        71
      8    41
  100  60
```

And then it looks like this:

```
     8
  71  41
100 60
```

And at last, it looks like this:

```
      8
  60    41
100  71
```

At this time, every non-leaf node, its value is greater than that of its children's.
So, after you delete the min value, the root of the min-heap above would be deleted, and result is this:

```
     41
  60    100
71
```

And if you delete the max value, that would be the last element that is deleted.
then the result would be this:

```
     8
  60    41
71
```

I hope this would help you to understand Heap.

Comment: I am sorry but is that a min. heap? I thought that is different from Min-Max heap...

Comment: There is actually another type of heap: min-max heap which involves both min and max heaps...

Comment: @SilentKnight There exists really a _min-max heap_ data structure. [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_heap)'s the Wikipedia's related page, which isn't complete. However, you can check the original paper in the references of that same article.